# Showing new list element form on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

does anyone know how to show the new list element form on button click, that I have on my custom aspx page? Like when you have a sharepoint list and you click on "add item" and a new element form loads up in a new dialog window? I need the same thing to happen when I click on my button. I know how to do that in Sharepoint Designer, but I need to do it programmatically in visual studio. I assume Javascript must be involved in some way and I am terrible with it. Thaks in advance!

One more question - do you know of a way to refresh the original page, the one that has the button, upon closing of the dialog window? 
Here is the scenario:

1. I press the button,
2. it opens the dialog window,
3. I add an element to a Sharepoint list via it,
4. I close the dialog window,
5. I need the original page refreshed, so it repopulates the
   DropDownList and adds the title of this new list item to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript code to achieve that varies with the type of list you are using (Tasks, document library, etc).

To open a Sharepoint dialog window you can use the following javascript:

```
var options = {
  url: '<url to the add item page>',
  title: '<Title of your Dialog>'
}; 

// add an event handler for the dialog closed callback
options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, portal_modalDialogClosedCallback);

void(SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options))

function portal_modalDialogClosedCallback(result, value) {
    if(result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) { 
        //alert("OK was clicked");
    } 
    if(result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) { 
        //alert("CANCEL was clicked");
    }

    window.frameElement.commitPopup(); // this will cause the list to refresh after the dialog closes
    // note: the above line only refreshes the List (which is the default Sharepoint OOB behavior anyway), to refresh the whole page use window.location.reload(); instead
}
```

The actual URL to use above varies with the type of list. Some examples:

- Document Library-based: `[url to your list, e.g. /Lists/MyList]/Forms/Upload.aspx`
- Announcements: `[url to your list]/NewForm.aspx`
- Tasks: `[url to your list]/NewForm.aspx`

Hope this helps

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I needed, I wrapped your text in a function and called it from my button OnClientClick event. Thank you, this is the best reply yet.

Comment: One more question - do you know of a way to refresh the original page, the one that has the button, upon closing of the dialog window? Here is the scenario - 1)I press the button, 2)it opens the dialog window, 3)I add an element to a Sharepoint list via it, 4)I close the dialog window, 5)I need the original page refreshed, so it repopulates the DropDownList and adds the title of this new list item to it. If you know the answer, I would appreciate it a ton.

Comment: edited the question and the answer to reflect the updated scenario

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I was experimenting all this time and already tried that exact variant and for some reason window.frameElement.commitPopup() doesn't work, it says "window.frameElement is null or doesn't exist". My code is basically a copy of yours, except I replaced that line with "history.go(0)" and now it works. Regardless, thanks for your help. EDIT: window.location.reload() didn't work either for some reason.

Comment: window.location.reload() is basic javascript so it should work "always" .. :)
btw, you can also try SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); for refreshing only the List

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `AjaxControlToolkit`, especially [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx)

Comment: After installing ajaxcontroltoolkit, it seems to me sharepoint refuses to work with it.

Comment: I don't know if it works with Sharepoint. I thought this was just an example since you wrote "**Like** when you have a sharepoint list..." Edit: Maybe this link will help you: http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2007/02/26/using-the-ajax-control-toolkit-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it to work with Sharepoint by following the instructions from your link, I will update if it helps with my original issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have the use the [Modal Dialog Framework](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx) and the JS client object model.

Comment: Just by skipping through the article, it seems it is exactly what I need, thank you!